# Why do I need to include both the iostream and fstream headers to open a file

Tags: c++, iostream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("test.txt");
  return 0;
}
```

fstream is derived from iostream, why should we include both in the code above?

I removed fstream, however, there is an error with ofstream. My question is ofstream is derived from ostream, why fstream is needed to make it compile?

Comment: Is it really necessary to title everything "One questions about..."?

Comment: Changed the title to something meaningful. @skydoor: remember that the question title is supposed to tell people what your question *is*. Just saying that your question is indeed a question doesn't really tell us anything we didn't know.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to include `fstream` because that's where the definition of the `ofstream` class is.

You've kind of got this backwards: since `ofstream` derives from `ostream`, the `fstream` header includes the `iostream` header, so you could leave out `iostream` and it would still compile. But you can't leave out `fstream` because then you don't have a definition for `ofstream`.

Think about it this way. If I put this in `a.h`:

```
class A {
  public:
    A();
    foo();
};
```

And then I make a class that derives from `A` in `b.h`:

```
#include <a.h>

class B : public A {
  public:
    B();
    bar();
};
```

And then I want to write this program:

```
int main()
{
  B b;
  b.bar();

  return 0;
}
```

Which file would I have to include? `b.h` obviously. How could I include only `a.h` and expect to have a definition for `B`?

Remember that in C and C++, `include` is literal. It literally pastes the contents of the included file where the `include` statement was. It's not like a higher-level statement of "give me everything in this family of classes".

Comment: Can you really omit "iostream" when including "fstream"? I get "‘cout’ was not declared in this scope" error even after using "using namespace std". Why is this so?

Comment: @Alby It seems [`fstream`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.0/fstream-source.html) includes `istream` and `ostream` but not `iostream`.  `iostream` is unnecessary in the original example not because `fstream` includes it but because the example doesn't actually use anything from `iostream`.

Comment: @piedar your link only describes the behaviour of g++  , this is not required by the C++ standard and other implementations may differ

Comment: "the fstream header includes the iostream header, so you could leave out iostream and it would still compile." this is wrong - trying to include fstream and leaving out iostream makes cout undeclared identifier

Answer (score 6):

`std::ofstream` is defined in the `<fstream>` standard library header.

You need to include that header for its definition so that you can instantiate it.

Comment: so why ofstream is derived from ostream?

Comment: Because it is an output stream.

Answer (score 0):

The typedef `ofstream` and its associated class template are defined by `#include <fstream>` , so you need that header.

For your actual program, `#include <iostream>` is not needed.  But you may wish to use your `fstream` object with some functions which operate on `ostream` or `istream`s .

Those functions are not defined by `#include <fstream>` and you need to include the right header for any functions you do use.   Some implementations might cause `#include <fstream>` to also include `<iostream>` but this is not guaranteed by the C++ Standard.

For example, this code:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("test.txt");

myfile << 1;
```

requires `#include <ostream>`  (or , since C++11, `#include <iostream>` which is guaranteed to bring in `#include <ostream>`).