# Why include both <iostream> and <fstream>

Tags: c++, stream, iostream, fstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I need to include both the iostream and fstream headers to open a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451681/why-do-i-need-to-include-both-the-iostream-and-fstream-headers-to-open-a-file)

I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   std::ofstream file_out("file.txt");
   file_out.close();

   return 0;
}
```

`std::ofstream` is defined in `<iostream>`, but compiling this code I obtain the following error:

```
error: variable 'std::ofstream file_out' has initializer but incomplete type
```

I discovered that if I also include `<fstream>` the error disappears and the code compiles. Why have I to include `<fstream>` if `std::ofstream` is included in `<iostream>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `std::ofstream` is defined in `<iostream>`

Nope. It could be *declared* there, but it's defined in `fstream`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo: You mean to have an `ofstream`, but your code says `ostream`. The latter is only a base class and can't be instantiated directly. (And you need the `<fstream>` header for it, not `<iostream>`.)

Comment: @R.M.: But now your claim that `ofstream` is defined in `iostream` is just plain dubious, non? (And in fact it blatantly is not.)

Comment: Non. My question comes from the fact that the error I obtained is not `undefined symbol`or something like that

Comment: @R.M.: "undefined symbol" is a linker error, not a compiler error. Are you sure you're not confusing declaration and definition?

Answer (score 0):

Because definition is in `#include <fstream>`  . You should also look at:

[Why do I need to include both the iostream and fstream headers to open a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451681/why-do-i-need-to-include-both-the-iostream-and-fstream-headers-to-open-a-file) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

So, C++ standard says nothing about includes of header-files in other header-files. For construct and use `std::ofstream` - you should include `fstream` header.