# Creating an ofstream if needed

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ofstream

I am sorry if this is a completely silly question, but I am having trouble with it nonetheless.

I am trying to pass two `std::string fileNames` to a function `foo` as follows:

> foo(int SomeValue, std::string fileName1, std::string fileName2)

I then want to check whether they both have a have a fileName longer than `""` as follows:

```
bool hasFile1 = true;
if(fileName1.empty())
{
    hasFile1 = false;
}
```

My problem has been arising since I want to be able to create an `ofstream` if `hasFile1 == true` and the same for `hasFile2`, both of which should be usable later in the function `foo`.

I have tried doing things like:

```
std::ofstream file1;
if(hasFile1)
{
    file1 = new std::ofstream(fileName1);
}
```

but the problem with this is that file1 is an incomplete type. Another method I tried was

```
std::ofstream* data;
if(hasFile1)
{
    data = new std::ofstream(fileName1)/std::ofstream(fileName1);
}
```

and all the various combinations all either give a incomplete type not allowed error or I cannot assign to the pointer.

The main point of the question is how do you allocate an `ofstream` so that you do not need to maintain 3 blocks of code that have various combinations of which `ofstreams` are being used?

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: `bool hasFile1 = !fileName1.empty();` - no need to write 4 lines when one will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "incomplete type" error will be because you haven't included `<fstream>` to get the definition of `ofstream`.

The first won't work because you're trying to assign a pointer (returned by `new`) to an object. In most cases, you would assign an object instead; but unfortunately streams aren't assignable, even by moving.

The second would work (once `ofstream` has been defined), but is a bad idea since you now have a raw pointer to a dynamically allocated resource. You're quite likely not to delete it correctly, giving memory leaks or other problems.

This can be mitigated by using a smart pointer rather than a raw pointer; but in the case of `ofstream`, you can simply leave it closed if you don't have a file to open:

```
std::ofstream file1;
if(hasFile1) {
    file1.open(fileName1);
}
```

Also, beware that you're not initialising `hasFile1` properly; and that you can't usually compare C-style strings using `==`. You want something more like

```
bool hasFile1 = (fileName1[0] != '\0');
```

or, if you change the file name arguments to the more friendly `std::string`

```
bool hasFile1 = !fileName1.empty();
```

Comment: Edited the question to reflect the c++ like strings and it was a case of including fstream.

Answer (score 1):

As you pass the strings as pointer, you try to compare them with another pointer (the literal `""`) which will *never* be true (unless, of course, you pass the string literal `""` *and* the compiler only keeps one copy of that specific string literal so the pointer to that literal is shared).

Either use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for strings, or if you want old C-style string pointer use [`std::strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) to check for empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison of a `const char*` in  `if(fileName1 == "")` might not do what you expect. It compares two `const char*` pointers, not their values. Use `strlen()` (check for zero) or `strcmp()` to compare C strings.

And did you include `fstream` ?

Comment: check for empty C string is best done as `if (!*str)`

Comment: I included iostream, so I suppose that would also include fstream

Comment: @Alex: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451681/why-do-i-need-to-include-both-the-iostream-and-fstream-headers-to-open-a-file

Comment: @bobah That is very true, however it is much more "cleaner" when trying to explain (at least for someone who starts learning C) to have an explicit function call.