# aggregate 'std::ofstream archivo' has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do a program with which I can save the name of a user within a text file 
Anyone know how to fix this or if you plan everything I wrote this wrong?

I want the program to ask the user if the name is correct or want to fix it (s to save the file) and (N to return to Enter the name before saved) do not know if the rest of the code is good but the problem I have is that when compile the program to run it jumps the error: aggregate 'std::ofstream archivo' has incomplete type and cannot be defined

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
void escribir();
escribir();
escribir();
char Si[1];
char No[1];
char nombre[30];

cout<<"Ingrese un nombre de usuario :D\n";
cin.getline(nombre,30,'\n');
ofstream archivo;

archivo.open("Datos1.txt",ios::out);

if(archivo.fail()){
    cout<<"Algo salio mal o-O";
    exit(1);
}
archivo<<nombre;

}
```

I expected that if the user pressed the S key after the name was entered, this will save the ". txt" and when you press N return to the option to enter the name

Comment: You forgot to add `#include <fstream>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451681/why-do-i-need-to-include-both-the-iostream-and-fstream-headers-to-open-a-file