# C++ string question - how to access string elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring

I have this simple code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;

    s[0]='A';
    cout << "s is: " << s << endl
         << "s[0] is: " << s[0] << endl;
}
```

why is s empty but s[0] has value of 'A'? can C++ strings be assigned values to its elements directly via index? Thanks!

Comment: What compiler and settings are you using for this? This doesn't compile for me with gcc and --std=c++11.

*disregard this comment, gcc doesn't make sense. Needed to g++.

Comment: You don't need `<fstream>` for `std::cout` and `std::string`.

Comment: good point. fstream include iostream according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451681/why-do-i-need-to-include-both-the-iostream-and-fstream-headers-to-open-a-file which is wrong

Answer (score 4):

This is undefined behavior. The string `s` is empty. Until C++11 you can't access `s[0]`. Since C++11 you can read `s[0]` but you can't write it.

You could resize the string with

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    s.resize(1);

    s[0]='A';
    cout << "s is: " << s << endl
         << "s[0] is: " << s[0] << endl;
}
```

Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at

Comment: s[0] was clearly written with the value 'A' and read as value 'A', even though string s is empty

Comment: @user526427 That's called undefined behavior. Anything could happen. Even seemingly correct behavior.

Comment: @user526427 it's like an array `int a[2];`. In most cases you can write to `a[10]` and read the correct value from that element. But this causes undefined behavior in your program and it could crash with strange errors.

Answer (score 1):

> why is s empty

Because you default-constructed it, so it is initially empty, and you did not do anything to allocate memory for its character storage.

> but s[0] has value of 'A'?

It does not. You are assigning `'A'` to memory that has not been allocated yet.

> can C++ strings be assigned values to its elements directly via index?

Yes, but only for *valid* indexes in the range of `0..size()-1` when `size()` is > 0. In your example, index 0 is not valid because `s.size()` is 0.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;

    s.resize(1); // <-- add this!

    s[0]='A';
    cout << "s is: " << s << endl
         << "s[0] is: " << s[0] << endl;
}
```